# Object-oriented programming & transactions

Tags: oop, architecture

A little intro:

Class contains fields and methods (let me skip properties this time).
Fields represent a *state* of the class.
Methods describe *behavior* of the class.

In a well-designed class, a method won't change the class's state if it throws an exception, right? (In other words, whatever happens, class's state shouldn't be corrupted)

Question:

Is there a framework, a design pattern, best practice or a programming language to call a sequence of methods in a transactional style, so that either class's state don't get changed (in case of exception), or everything succeeds?

E.g.:

```
// the class foo is now in the state S1
foo.MoveToState2();
// it is now (supposed to be) in the state S2
foo.MoveToFinalState();
// it is now (supposed to be) in the state, namely, S3
```

Surely, an exception might occur both in `MoveToState2()` and `MoveToFinalState()`. But from this block of code I want the class `foo` to be either in the state S1 or S3.

This is a simple scenario with a single class involved, no `if`'s, no `while`'s, no side effects, but I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

> The memento pattern is a software design pattern that provides the ability to restore an object to its previous state (undo via rollback).

Comment: As I say in my post, the memento is used more in a gui environment, for persistence and undo/redo. Although the basic concept is the same (create another class that represents the state) you shouldn't transit to the new state until it's completely safe to do so. That suggest to try to create the new state, and only if this step succeed, to change the state in the new one.

Answer (score 5):

Not the most efficient method, but you could have an object that represents your transactional data. When you start a transaction, make a copy of the data and perform all operations on that. When the transaction ends successfully, move the copy to your real data - this can be done using pointers, so need not be too inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Functional programming is a paradigm that seems to fit well to transactional computations. Since no side-effects are allowed without explicit declaration, you have full control of all data flow.

Therefore *software transactional memory* can be expressed easily in functional terms - See [STM for F#](http://cs.hubfs.net/blogs/hell_is_other_languages/archive/2008/01/16/4565.aspx)

The key idea is the concept of [*monads*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions). A monad can be used to model an arbitrary computation through two primitives: *Return* to return a value and *Bind* to sequence two computations. Using these two, you can model a transactional monad that controls and saves all state in form of continuations.

One could try to model these in an object-oriented way through a [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)+[Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) pattern, but generally, transactions in imperative languages (like the common OO-ones) are much more difficult to implement since you can perform arbitrary side-effects. But of course you can think of an object defining a transaction scope, that saves, validates and restores data as needed, given they expose a suitable interface for this (the patterns I mentioned above).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest and most reliable "pattern" to use here is an immutable data structure.

Instead of writing:

```
foo.MoveToState2();
foo.MoveToFinalState();
```

You write:

```
MyFoo foo2 = foo.MoveToState2();
MyFoo finalFoo = foo2.MoveToFinalState();
```

And implement the methods accordingly - that is, `MoveToState2` does not actually change anything about `MyFoo`, it creates a new `MyFoo` that is in state 2.  Similarly with the final state.

This is how the string classes in most OO languages work.  Many OO languages are also starting to implement (or have already implemented) immutable collections.  Once you have the building blocks, it's fairly straightforward to create an entire immutable "entity".

Answer (score 1):

This would be pretty ugly to implement everywhere, but just saving the state locally, then restoring it in the case of an exception would work in simple scenarios.  You'd have to catch and rethrow the exception, which may lose some context in some languages.  It might be better to wrap it if possible to retain the context.

```
try {
   save state in local variables
   move to new state
} catch (innerException) {
   restore state from local variables
   throw new exception( innerException )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Transactional memory fits here the best.
2. An option could be a transactional storage. Sample implementation you can find here:
   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Transactional_Repository.aspx
3. Memento pattern
4. Also let me describe a possible pattern on how to implement such behavior: 
   Define a base class `TransactionalEntity`. This class contains dictionary of properties.
   All your transactional classes inherit from the `TransactionalEntity` and should operate over some sort of **Dependency Properties/Fields**, i.e. properties(getters/setters) which store it's values not in local class fields, but in dictionary, which is stored in the base class.
   Then you define `TransactionContext` class. `TransactionContext` class internally contains a set of dictionaries (one dictionary for each entity that participates in the transaction) and when a transactional entity participates in transaction, it writes all data to the dictionary in the transaction context. Then all you need is basically four methods:

   TransactionContext.StartTransaction();
   TransactionalEntity.JoinTransaction(TransactionContext context); //if your language/framework supports Thread Static fields, then you do not need this method
   TransactionContext.CommitTransaction();
   TransactionContext.RollbackTransaction();

To sum up, you need to store state in base class `TransactionalEntity` and during transaction `TransactionalEntity` will cooperate with `TransactionContext`.

I hope, I've explained it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

When using object copy approach, you have to watch out that the statements to be rolled-back are only affecting the object's or data itself (and aggregates).

But things are getting really difficult if the side-effects of the statements are "more external". For example I/O operations, network calls. You always have to analyze the overall state-changes of your statements.

It gets also really tricky if you touch static data (or evil mutable singletons). Reverting this data isolated is difficult, because other threads could have modified them in between (you could face lost updates).

Reverting/rollback to the past is often not so trivial ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider the saga pattern, you could pass a copy of the objects current state into MoveToState2 and if it throws an exception you could catch that internally and use the copy of the original state to rollback. You would have to do the same with MoveToState3 too. If however the server crashed during a rollback you might still get corrupted state, that's why databases are so good.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Command Pattern could be well suited to this problem.
[Linky.](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was astonished that no one suggested explicitly the simplest pattern to use .. the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

In this way you can also eliminate that 'finalState' method and just use 'handle()'.
How do you know which final state is? 
The memento pattern is best used with the Command pattern, and usually applies to GUI operations to implement the undo/redo feature.

> Fields represent a state of the class

Fields represents the state of the **instanced object**. You use many times wrong definitions of the OOP terms. Review and correct.