# Can we implement Transaction on C# objects?

Tags: c#, .net

Can we use transaction on C# objects.

Does all the Transactions are only for Relational Database like MSSQL, ORACLE, etc...??

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020660/transactions-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is called [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). Since this is currently an open area of research and there is no native C# language support at the moment, you might be better off using the [existing synchronization options for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx), such as the `lock` keyword, monitors, wait handles, etc.

If you really need advanced transactional features, there are a lot of library implementations, see this list in Wikipedia for some examples:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#C.23

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested by [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). It exists one implementation in the .NET world, named [STM.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee334183.aspx).

> Software Transactional Memory
>   (STM.NET) is a mechanism for efficient
>   isolation of shared state. The
>   programmer demarcates a region of code
>   as operating within a transaction that
>   is "atomic" and "isolated" from other
>   transacted code running concurrently.

Here is the blog of the Microsoft STM.NET team : http://blogs.msdn.com/stmteam/

Comment: You are right about STM, but don't forget to note that STM is still in research, development and I wouldn't use it in production software.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice discussion how to implement transaction in OOP take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974508/object-oriented-programming-transactions). There the memento and state pattern are highlighted to achieve transactional behaviour (among other methods).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Software Transactional Memory (STM.NET).

It didn't make it into .Net 4 but is available as a separate download

Answer (score 1):

There was an [Interesting article](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/01/03/ABriefRetrospectiveOnTransactionalMemory.aspx) on Joe Duffy's blog about the attempt to do Transactional Memory at MS. If I were to sum it up, I would say: Only do this yourself if it is for fun.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Microsoft has moved away from stm. Some of the reasoning is given here https://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/STM-Dropped although i am not fully sold on its weaky atomic in place modification argument. I think a strongly atomic transaction where all the objects state must lie inside a transaction still has merit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL-like transactioning for c# objects, but if this because you have threading problems, you should use `lock`:

```
lock (myList)
{
    if (myList.Count > 0)
        myList.Clear();
}
```

This simply clears a list but ensures it can't be modified by another thread at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TransactionScope Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

Comment: this is completely incorrect, the TransactionScope is only used for DB

Comment: Humm.. no. It can be used for anything that implements IEnlistmentNotification